# Facebook authentication works in pageload but not in a button? MVC4 c#

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

Ive been trying this for two days but I dont understand what might be the problem.

1. I have an authentication to facebook where I redirect a user to facebook so they can authenticate and then I 
   make a callback to my site so I get the info I need for them to register into my database.

Problem: This doesn't work when pressing a button but works if the `facebookauthentication` method is in my `actionresult`
(without httppost) so do you have any idea on why this keeps occuring?

Here is my code:

```
   public override ActionResult Index(ExternalLoginBlock model)
        {


            return PartialView(model);
        }
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Facebook(ExternalLoginBlock currentBlock)
        {
            JObject json = CheckAuthorization();
            FacebookInformation user = GetFacebookInfo(json);
            SignIn(user);

        var model = new ExternalLoginBlockViewModel(currentBlock);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
    public JObject CheckAuthorization()
    {       
        string app_id = "xxxxxx";
        string app_secret = "xxxxxx";
        string scope = "publish_stream,manage_pages";

        if (Request["code"] == null)
        {
             Response.Redirect(string.Format(
                "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",
               app_id, "http://global.iobffp.com/SIGN-IN/", scope)); // this redirect the user and then the
                                                                     // "code" gets value.
        }
        if(Request["code"] != null) // if it goes in here everythings fine.
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}",
                app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope, Request["code"].ToString(), app_secret);
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();

                foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
                {
                    //meh.aspx?token1=steve&token2=jake&...
                    tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                        token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
                }
            }
            string access_token = tokens["access_token"];

            var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);

            var query = client.Get("/me?fields=picture,id,name,email,birthday,hometown");
            JsonObject result1;
            result1 = (Facebook.JsonObject)client.Get(query);

           json  = JObject.Parse(result1.ToString());
            return json;
        }
        return json;
    }
```

So the problem is. If I have  this in my override `actionresult` everything works fine but if it's in my `httppost` facebook `actionresult` it wont work.
any ideas?